# How to make image stay at its size when i zoom the browser

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a landing page consist only of images, basically its more like a banner. But the problem is, when i try to zoom in or zoom out on my chrome the image will resize itself. I have tried using width 100% and height auto but the problem still arise.
Can anyone help me solve the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: This might be in the hands of the browser, and the exact behavior could even vary across different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, 100% and auto are relative values, you want static, ie set width and heighth to some value via css.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
<div class="cover">
  <img src="/set path" alt="" />
</div>
```

Write **CSS** *like this way*

```
.cover {
   width:100vh;
   height:100vh;
   float:left;
}
.cover img {
   width:100%;
   height:100%; /* or you can set `vh` height */
}
```